# Java hashset vs Arrays.sort

Tags: java, arrays, hashset

I am trying to solve the below 'codility' exercise:

A zero-indexed array A consisting of N different integers is given. The array contains integers in the range [1..(N + 1)], which means that exactly one element is missing.

Your goal is to find that missing element.

Write a function:

```
class Solution { public int solution(int[] A); }
```

that, given a zero-indexed array A, returns the value of the missing element.

For example, given array A such that:

```
  A[0] = 2
  A[1] = 3
  A[2] = 1
  A[3] = 5
```

the function should return 4, as it is the missing element.

Assume that:

```
    N is an integer within the range [0..100,000];
    the elements of A are all distinct;
    each element of array A is an integer within the range [1..(N + 1)].
```

Complexity:

```
    expected worst-case time complexity is O(N);
    expected worst-case space complexity is O(1), beyond input storage (not counting the storage required for input arguments).
```

Elements of input arrays can be modified.

**I came up with two solutions:**

1) Gives 100%/100%

```
class Solution {

    public int solution(int[] A) {
        int previous = 0;
        if (A.length != 0) {
            Arrays.sort(A);
            for (int i : A) {
                if (++previous != i) {
                    return previous;
                }
            }
        }
        return ++previous;
    }
}
```

2) Gives an error  WRONG ANSWER, got 65536 expected 100001

```
class SolutionHS {

    public int solution(int[] A) {
        int previous = 0;
        HashSet<Integer> hs = new HashSet<>();
        if (A.length != 0) {
            for (int a : A) {
                hs.add(a);
            }

            for (Integer i : hs) {
                if (++previous != i) {
                    return previous;
                }
            }
        }
        return ++previous;
    }
}
```

My question is:
Shouldn't both approaches (using hashset and Arrays.sort) work the same way?
If not can you tell me what the difference is?

Comment: You can just sum the elements and then subtract from the expected sum.

Comment: Your codes have  higher time or space complexity than expected. In 1 ) Time is O(nlogn) and in 2 ) Space - O(n)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HashSet` is not sorted, so when you iterate over the elements of the Set, you don't get them in an ascending order, as your code expects. If you used a `TreeSet` instead of `HashSet`, your code would work.

The `HashSet` solution will give the correct answer if you change the second loop to :

```
for (int i = 0; i <= A.length; i++) {
    if (!hs.contains(i)) {
        return i;
    }
}
```

This loop explicitly checks whether each integer in the relevant range appears in the `HashSet` and returns the first (and only one) which doesn't.

Anyway, both your implementations don't meet the `O(n)` running time and `O(1)` space requirements.

In order you meet the required running time and space, you should calculate the sum of the elements of the array and subtract that sum from `(A.length+1)*A.length/2`.